# StopPropagation on Mat-Menu except certain click event - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, stoppropagation

I implemented an angular application (@latest version), in my implementation I used a mat-menu to show some custom component which contains some customized options along with a apply button. By default, if we do any click in the menu popover screen immediately it will close. So I added a `stopPropagation` on my custom component to prevent closing popover action.

But I need to close the menu pop-over on apply button click event. But its failing because the `stopPropagation` in the parent level prevents the button close action.

How to escape from `stopPropagation` only for the specified button.

Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-menu-stop-propagation?embed=1

**File: app.component.html**

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <menu-toolbar  (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"></menu-toolbar>
</mat-menu>
```

**File: menu-toolbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './menu-toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './menu-toolbar.component.css' ]
})
export class MenuToolbarComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  applyChanges(): void {

    // some actions done

    console.log('Changes applied successfully...');
  }
}
```

**File: menu-toolbar.component.html**

```
<div>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #2</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #3</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<button mat-button (click)="applyChanges($event)">Apply</button>
```

> Note: If I add the `stopPropagation` to the checkbox, it closes the
>   pop-over if I click outside the checkbox. So, I added in the component
>   level.

Kindly assist me how to escape from `stopPropagation` only for the "**Apply**" button.

Comment: event using stopPropagation in parent click outside closes the menu!?

Comment: @FatemeFazli - If clicking outside the menu-popover, it will close and no issues on that. If we click inside the custom component which is loaded as menu, which should not close and close only on after clicking the apply button.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `stopPropagation` on
`<menu-toolbar></menu-toolbar>`
and put it on the `div` like this:

```
<div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <mat-checkbox>Item #1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #2</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox>Item #3</mat-checkbox>
</div>
<button mat-button (click)="applyChanges($event)">Apply</button>
```

Comment: If you click outside of the button and checkbox div area, it will close the pop-over.

Comment: As I understand from the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview), it is not possible to prevent the default behavior and suppress closing or explicitly call the close method. This would be i nice feature request.